# Require interface on method argument

Tags: php

Let's say I have class:

```
class Foo implements FooInterface{

   private $a=2;

   //implements sum from interface
   public function sum(){
      return $a+$a;
   }
}
```

Now I have another class:

```
class Bar{

    private $foo;

    public function __construct($foo){
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}
```

PHP let's us force object type while calling methods:

```
function abc(Xyz $xyz){}
```

Does it supports forcing interfaces? Can I force constructor of `Bar` to accept only objects that implement `FooInterface`?

Comment: I do it all the time. What happened when you tried?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And it works just like you think it does.

```
class Foo implements FooInterface {}

class Bar{
    public function __construct(FooInterface $foo) {}
}
```

#### Also Note:

- It isn't called "forcing", it's called *type-hinting*. Here's the **[Manual Entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)**
- Type-hinting works with concrete classes (hint for Foo), classes that extend another class (`Foo extends Baz`, hinting for Baz will allow for Foo), and interfaces.